# Accounting for reflections and rotations in combinatorial strings taken from multisets

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

I have a $n$-element string taken from a $k$-element multiset. I want to treat reflections and rotations of strings as really the same string. How do I count that?

Edit: Here's an example. I have a string $(A,A,A,A,C,C,D,D,D)$  and I want to count all the permutations of it, accounting for reflections being the same, and further that if we consider the "ends" of the string as connected, each rotation of that will end up being identical as well.

Comment: check for 'necklaces' and 'bracelets' and their counting on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29

Comment: That's very interesting, but I think my problem is actually slightly different than how I stated it. I said that I have an $n$-element string from a $k$-element multiset, but I realize essentially I have one string $s$ with elements from a $k$-element multiset, and I want to count the number of ways of sliding the string along or reflecting it down the middle, etc. Any advice there?

Comment: Could you clarify your question with an example? That would help a lot.

Comment: To take the effect of symmetries into consideration, you need to look for Burnside's lemma or Polya's counting theory. Look them up in Wikipedia for starters.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the wiki link given, your example is a size n=9 bracelet over k=4 colours.
As a necklace it has $N_k(n)=\frac{\sum _d^{\text{Divisors}[n]} \phi (d) k^{n/d}}{n}$  so 29144 different constellations.
As a bracelet, it has $B_k(n)=\text{If}\left[\text{EvenQ}[n],\frac{1}{4} (k+1) k^{n/2},\frac{1}{2} k^{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\right]+N_k(n)/2$
so 15084 different ones.